# Checkbox turning multiple values true

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, checkbox, boolean

I've been stuck of this for a while and would love some insight.

When I add a new user or source and check the drawn checkbox, it causes the bool to be true when checked, as expected.

However it also checks all the other users connected to that source as true or false.

[before]

[image: [1]]

[after]

[image: [2]]

This only occurs when I load the XML file into my program that already had existing data, then add new Users or Sources via the UI.

this is a part of the LoadXML Method.

```
// Load the source list
        sourceProps.SystemSources.Clear();
        fCMUserSourceBindingSource.Clear();
        fCMSourceBindingSource.Clear();

        foreach (FusionSource src in fusionSystem.sourceList)
        {
            FCMSource fSource = new FCMSource(src);
            sourceProps.SystemSources.Add(fSource);
            fCMSourceBindingSource.Add(fSource);
            fCMUserSourceBindingSource.Add(fSource);
        }
        txtSourceID.Text = sourceProps.GenerateNextSourceId();

        // Load the user data from the fusionSystem object.
        userProfile.SystemUserList.Clear();

        //currently clears grid. might need to clear list instead
        fCMUserBindingSource.Clear();

        foreach (FusionUser usr in fusionSystem.userList)
        {
            FCMUser fUser = new FCMUser(usr);
            userProfile.SystemUserList.Add(fUser);
            fCMUserBindingSource.Add(fUser);

            foreach (FusionSourcePermission srcPerm in usr.SourcePermissionList)
            {
                FCMSource fSource = new FCMSource(srcPerm);
                fUser.fusionUserSources.Add(fSource);
            }
        }
        AddColumnsUsersToSourceAllocation();
        txtUserID.Text = userProfile.GenerateNextUserId();

        // Load the zone group data from the fusionSystem object
        zoneProps.systemZoneGroupList.Clear();
        fCMZoneGroupBindingSource.Clear();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

The ListView is not binded and all the 'checking' is done programmatically when the user activates the click event.

```
private void lstSourceToUser_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex > 1)
        {
            int usrIndex = userProfile.GetUserIndexByID(e.Header.Name);
            int srcIndex = userProfile.GetUsersSourceIndex(e.Header.Name, e.Item.SubItems[0].Text);
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(g,new Point((e.Bounds.X + e.Bounds.Width/2 -10 ),(e.Bounds.Y)), userProfile.SystemUserList[usrIndex].fusionUserSources[srcIndex].UserSourceChkBox.MyCheckedState ? CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal : CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal);
        }
        else
            // Draw the other subitems with default drawing.
            e.DrawDefault = true;
    }
```

**Edit**

This is the FCMSource constructor.

```
        public FCMSource(string sourceId, string sourceName, string icnId, string lstIndx)
    {
        id = sourceId;
        icon = icnId;
        name = sourceName;
        listIndex = lstIndx;
        UserSourceCheckState = false;
        UserSourceChkBox = new MyCheckBoxItem(false);
    }

    public FCMSource(FCMSource fSource, bool chk)
    {
        name = fSource.name;
        icon = fSource.icon;
        id = fSource.id;
        listIndex = fSource.listIndex;
        UserSourceCheckState = chk ? true : false;
        UserSourceChkBox = new MyCheckBoxItem(chk);
    }
```

And this is the FCMUser constructor which contains the different Sources.

```
 public FCMUser(string userid, string nm, string icn, string pinNo, CheckBox pinEn, string lstIndx)
    {
        id = userid;
        name = nm;
        icon = icn;
        pin = pinNo;
        pinEnabled = pinEn.CheckState;
        chkBoxPINEnable = new MyCheckBoxItem(false);
        fusionUserSources = new List<FCMSource>();
        ListIndex = lstIndx;
        updateCheckbox();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand either your method or your problem, but it seems like a simple binding issue.  If you've bound them all to one property, then of course they would all change together.  Inspect the binding to see if they match.

Comment: @DonBoitnott +1 I was about to say the same just a second later.

Comment: The BindingSource isnt binded to the ListView which the checkboxes appear on.

Comment: Could the problem be in the fact that you're adding the same instance of an object to the .SystemUserList and to the binding source. I'm even not sure, but I suppose it could somehow make all the object change when one is changed. But it probably won't work, so it would be nice if you could share a bit more of your constructor code, so that we can see if there is some unwanted dependency in your data source constructor.

Comment: Added the constructors. Apologies for the lack of information, still new to stackoverflow and programming in general

Comment: I meant i.e. the `userProfile` variable and the constructor of the class it is. And about the `fCMUserBindingSource` I presume it's just an instance of the `BindingSource` class. I'm quite sure the mistake is somewhere there and would suggest you to try not to add the same ` FCMUser fUser = new FCMUser(usr);` object to both lists in this loop: `foreach (FusionUser usr in fusionSystem.userList)`